# SQL scan a list for any bad items, and for the time duration between first question and last question?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using Microsoft SSMS- I have a checklist for people to fill out, that goes to a SQL table for checklist responses- it tracks the checklist Id, the question Ids of the questions on the checklist, whether the response was good or bad, and the time the question was answered. For example, if there are 10 questions on the checklist, it will create 10 rows, that all have ChecklistId of 1, QuestionId #1-10, good and bad responses depending how people respond, and the time that each question was answered.

I need to write a query that returns the checklist Ids, whether each checklist has at least one bad response, and the duration of time between starting and ending the checklist. I think I have the duration figured out, but that check that there is a bad response has me stumped. Here is what I have so far:

```
DECLARE @StartEndStamps TABLE
(
    ChecklistId INT,
    FirstResponse DATETIME,
    LastResponse DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @StartEndStamps
SELECT DISTINCT 
ChecklistId,
MIN(ResponseDate),
MAX(ResponseDate)
FROM db.checklistResponses
GROUP BY ChecklistId

SELECT DISTINCT 
r.ChecklistId AS ChecklistNumber,
CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM db.checklistResponses r WHERE r.Response = 'bad') 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HasBadResponse,
DATEDIFF(SECOND, s.FirstResponse, s.LastResponse) AS Duration
FROM db.checklistResponses r
INNER JOIN @StartEndStamps s 
    ON s.ChecklistId = r.ChecklistId
```

Any solutions or optimizations would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: You can probably do this with window functions, you certainly don't need a temp table. Sample data and expected results would help immensely.

Comment: You can provide demo DDL/DML like this: `DECLARE @Table TABLE (Col1 INT, Col2 VARCHAR(20), ...); INSERT INTO @Table (Col1, Col2, ...) VALUES (1, 'xyz', ...), (2, 'abc', ...);` This helps folks answer your question.

Comment: right now your query will always return 1 for all checklists. You need to *correlate* the subquery with your main table, something like: `...(select 1 from db.checklistResponses r2 where r2.checklistid = r.checklistid and r2.response = 'bad')...`

Comment: I'll be sure to give a data example next time, but I believe siggemannen's answer does exactly what I need it to do. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

this is best code

```
SELECT 
(CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM db.checklistResponses r WHERE r.Response = 'bad') 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HasBadResponse,
DATEDIFF(SECOND, MIN(ResponseDate),MAX(ResponseDate)) AS Duration
FROM db.checklistResponses
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**